# TypeORM many to many relationship give duplicate row when saving

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Let's say I have some entities like this

**Project Entity**

```
@Entity()
export class ProjectEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => TagEntity)
    @JoinTable({ name: 'project_tag' })
    tags: Promise<TagEntity[]>;

}
```

**Tag Entity**

```
@Entity()
export class TagEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

}
```

**Project Tag Entity**

```
@Entity('project_tag')
export class ProjectTagEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  tagId: number;

  @Column({
    nullable: false,
  })
  projectId: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

when I save them such as like this:

```
//assume there is already saved row for project and tag entities right here
project.categories = [tag1, tag2];
await connection.manager.save(project);
```

why there are duplicate rows in project_tag table? for example previously there are already exist tag1 and tag2 relationship with the project but I save it for the second time and it gives duplicate rows in project_tag table. How do I able avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your id-columns in data-tables and in join-table. They should have same type. I had such problem and this was the case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thankss I re-check and your suggestion is true

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where the relationship between project and categories is defined. Also, you shouldn't need to type tags as `Promise<TagEntity[]>`. You should be able to type is simply as `TagEntity[]`.

Comment: I want to lazy load this behaviour, but for sure I try with `TagEntity[]` too but still got duplicate. I add Project Tag Entity to description